# draw path between two points on google maps

Tags: android, overlay, kml, google-maps-api-2

I am working on Android Google maps. I gone through

http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html

I am not able to draw full Path between two points if the distance is more than 200KM. How can  i draw full path between two points? is there any issue with license, if there is any license issue how can i approach to get license.

Thanks

Comment: Use google navigation URI with your source and destination lat/lon

Answer (score 1):

I managed to draw a path between two points using Google map android API v2. I posted its solution at that link. [Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)

Answer (score -1):

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

private Projection projection;  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoomview);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();        
    projection = mapView.getProjection();
    mapOverlays.add(new MyOverlay());        

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

class MyOverlay extends Overlay{

    public MyOverlay(){

    }   

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
        super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

    Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint(37423157, -122085008);

        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();

    Path    path = new Path();

    Projection  projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);
        projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);

        path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);

        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }
```