# Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: google-maps, path, google-maps-markers, routes, google-maps-android-api-2

Google changed its map API for Android and introduced API V2. The previous codes for drawing path are not working with API V2.

I have managed to draw a path with API V2. I had searched a lot for the solution but did not find any answer. So I am sharing its answer.

Comment: Hi zeeshan will i be able to fetch my nearby places using google maps android API V2 or we have to use only google places API ??? Any ideas

Answer (score 170, accepted):

First of all we will get source and destination points between which we have to draw route. Then we will pass these attribute to below function.

```
 public String makeURL (double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog ){
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
        urlString.append("?origin=");// from
        urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString( sourcelog));
        urlString.append("&destination=");// to
        urlString.append(Double.toString( destlat));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString( destlog));
        urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
        urlString.append("&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
        return urlString.toString();
 }
```

This function will make the url that we will send to get Direction API response. Then we will parse that response . The parser class is

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = sb.toString();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return json;

    }
}
```

This parser will return us string. We will call it like that.

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

Now we  will send this string to our drawpath function. The drawpath function is

```
public void drawPath(String  result) {

    try {
            //Tranform the string into a json object
           final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
           JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
           JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
           JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
           String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
           List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
           Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                    .addAll(list)
                                    .width(12)
                                    .color(Color.parseColor("#05b1fb"))//Google maps blue color
                                    .geodesic(true)
                    );
           /*
           for(int z = 0; z<list.size()-1;z++){
                LatLng src= list.get(z);
                LatLng dest= list.get(z+1);
                Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude,   dest.longitude))
                .width(2)
                .color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
            }
           */
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {

    }
}
```

Above code will draw the path on mMap. The code of decodePoly is

```
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng( (((double) lat / 1E5)),
                 (((double) lng / 1E5) ));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

As direction call may take time so we will do all this in Asynchronous task.
My Asynchronous task was

```
private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String url;
    connectAsyncTask(String urlPass){
        url = urlPass;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);   
        progressDialog.hide();        
        if(result!=null){
            drawPath(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: There is no direct way to remove path. We have to remove it manually.

Comment: If you write your MainActivity including this code here, it will be very helpful. PLEASE~!.. How many classes(java file) do you set in your app?...MainActivity.java and JSONParser.java, it's all??

Comment: Yes I only use these two classes. I think the code is clear. You just need two points(LatLng) to run that code.

Comment: @zeeshan0026..Thanks a lot..In your code "JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);", what is "(url)"?

Comment: @zeeshan0026..And Where do your"connectAsyncTask()"doing AsyncTask put in your MainActivity?..I can't find it in your code above.

Comment: url is the value we get from the makeURL() function. Yes I added the Async Task in MainActivity.

Comment: @zeeshan0026 I edited it for add steps and other features of directions do you have github? Can I upload to my gitHub I will name you.

Comment: @Fernando. Yes you can add. No problem.

Comment: I added the class to my repository and I modify it for allow multiple points and set marks for indications.
https://github.com/tato469/Android/tree/master/routes%20googleMaps%20v2

Comment: This works only with WiFi for me, I have no idea why. I tried on 3G, on HSPA, it just doesn't work. I think I get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT...

Comment: @zeeshan0026 Your code worked awesome. But I have a small doubt. If between two lat long, the road is not straight, then the path we are drawing will vary to the actual path. This kind of scenario will happen when the source and destination are longer distance. How to achieve that scenario? Please help me.

Comment: i am getting StringIndexOutofBoundsException in decodePoly method

Comment: Very nice coding. Btw if you want to use waypoints add the following:

        urlString.append("&waypoints=");// waypoints
        urlString.append(Double.toString(51.370789));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(Double.toString(4.473495));

You can separate multiple points be using the | char ==> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: the above code creates too many short Polylines which some times makes map laggy....We have better option, Just create one line by replacing following code in above code, `PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true); for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) { LatLng point = list.get(z); options.add(point); } line = myMap.addPolyline(options);`

Comment: I want to know if it is possible/legal to call this above API without API KEY as i don't see anyone mention about it.

Comment: @zeeshan0026 I do exactly as your codes, but it does not draw anything!

Comment: @ƒernandoValle What is steps in your codes? And by the way, i do exactly as answer's codes, but it does not draw anything! Should we write addMarkers? why we don't have this in this answer?!

Comment: Any limits or restriction from google using this api?

Comment: First of all Thank you for this...i have more question that is that possible that automatically get zoom google map to the direction of route...? Thank you

Comment: If you get the error `Requests to this API must be over SSL`, change `http` to `https`

Comment: Question, is it a free API provided by Google? I thought I'd use the Directions API, but it seems not.

Comment: Best Answer +1 Superb @zeeshan0026

Comment: I had to enable Google Places API for Android in [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/) and create a server key, and put it as `key` param in `makeURL` function otherwise I got `This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key`. Also, change url to `https` instead of `http` as AlvaroSantisteban mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Dont know whether I should put this as answer or not...

I used @Zeeshan0026's solution to draw the path...and the problem was that if I draw path once, and then I do try to draw path once again, both two paths show and this continues...paths showing even when markers were deleted... while, ideally, old paths' shouldn't be there once new path is drawn / markers are deleted..

going through some other question over SO, I had the following solution

I add the following function in Zeeshan's class

```
 public void clearRoute(){

         for(Polyline line1 : polylines)
         {
             line1.remove();
         }

         polylines.clear();

     }
```

in my map activity, before drawing the path, I called this function.. example usage as per my app is

```
private Route rt;

rt.clearRoute();

            if (src == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select your Source", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if (Destination == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select your Destination", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if (src.equals(Destination)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Source and Destinatin can not be the same..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{

                rt.drawRoute(mMap, MapsMainActivity.this, src,
                        Destination, false, "en");
            }
```

you can use `rt.clearRoute();` as per your requirements..
Hoping that it will save a few minutes of someone else and will help some beginner in solving this issue..

**Complete Class Code**

see on [github](https://github.com/zaffar-saffee/Android/blob/master/routes%20googleMaps%20v2/Route.java)

**Edit:**
here is part of code from mainactivity..

```
case R.id.mkrbtn_set_dest:
                    Destination = selmarker.getPosition();
                    destmarker = selmarker;
                    desShape = createRouteCircle(Destination, false);

                    if (src == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please select your Source first...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (src.equals(Destination)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Source and Destinatin can not be the same..",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                            rt.drawRoute(mMap, MapsMainActivity.this, src,
                                    Destination, false, "en");
                            src = null;
                            Destination = null;

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Internet Connection seems to be OFFLINE...!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    }

                    break;
```

**Edit 2**
as per comments

usage :

```
//variables as data members
GoogleMap mMap;
private Route rt;
static LatLng src;
static LatLng Destination;
//MapsMainActivity is my activity
//false for interim stops for traffic, google
// en language for html description returned

rt.drawRoute(mMap, MapsMainActivity.this, src,
                            Destination, false, "en");
```

Comment: Hi Zaffar, would it be possible to see your MapsMainActivity class?  I am new to Android and trying to make sense of this code.  I am not sure how you are passing all the arguments to drawroute() method.  Thank you for any help

Comment: thank you Zaffar, but I am still not seeing where a lot of these variables are created, ie destmarker.  And what is in the Destination class?  I will have a look and try again.

Answer (score 0):

in below code midpointsList is an ArrayList of waypoints

```
private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl(GoogleMap googleMap, LatLng startLatLng, LatLng endLatLng, ArrayList<LatLng> midpointsList) {
    String origin = "origin=" + startLatLng.latitude + "," + startLatLng.longitude;

    String midpoints = "";
    for (int mid = 0; mid < midpointsList.size(); mid++) {
        midpoints += "|" + midpointsList.get(mid).latitude + "," + midpointsList.get(mid).longitude;
    }

    String waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true" + midpoints + "|";

    String destination = "destination=" + endLatLng.latitude + "," + endLatLng.longitude;
    String key = "key=AIzaSyCV1sOa_7vASRBs6S3S6t1KofFvDhjohvI";

    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String params = origin + "&" + waypoints + "&" + destination + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;
    String output = "json";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + params;


    Log.e("url", url);
    parseDirectionApidata(url, googleMap);
    return url;
}
```

Then copy and paste this url in your browser to check And the below code is to parse the url

```
    private void parseDirectionApidata(String url, final GoogleMap googleMap) {

    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {

        AppUtill.getJsonWithHTTPPost(ViewMapActivity.this, 1, new ServiceCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void serviceCallBack(int id, JSONObject jsonResult) throws JSONException {

                if (jsonResult != null) {

                    Log.e("jsonRes", jsonResult.toString());

                    String status = jsonResult.optString("status");

                    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                        drawPath(jsonResult, googleMap);
                    }

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(ViewMapActivity.this, "Unable to parse Directions Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, url, jsonObject);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

And then pass the result to the drawPath method

```
    public void drawPath(JSONObject jObject, GoogleMap googleMap) {

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;
    List<LatLng> list = null;
    try {

        Toast.makeText(ViewMapActivity.this, "Drawing Path...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        /** Traversing all routes */
        for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
            jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            /** Traversing all legs */
            for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                /** Traversing all steps */
                for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    list = decodePoly(polyline);
                }
                Log.e("list", list.toString());
                routes.add(path);
                Log.e("routes", routes.toString());
                if (list != null) {
                    Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .addAll(list)
                            .width(12)
                            .color(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))//Google maps blue color #05b1fb
                            .geodesic(true)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

  private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

decode poly function is to decode the points(lat and long) provided by Directions API in encoded form

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution to **draw path with animation** and also **get time and distance** between two points.

**DirectionHelper.java**

```
public class DirectionHelper {

    public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray jRoutes;
        JSONArray jLegs;
        JSONArray jSteps;
        JSONObject jDistance = null;
        JSONObject jDuration = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
                jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {

                    /** Getting distance from the json data */
                    jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                    /** Getting duration from the json data */
                    jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                    /** Adding distance object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDistance);

                    /** Adding duration object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDuration);

                    jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude));
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude));
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


        return routes;
    }

    //Method to decode polyline points
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

**GetPathFromLocation.java**

```
public class GetPathFromLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    private Context context;
    private String TAG = "GetPathFromLocation";
    private LatLng source, destination;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> wayPoint;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private boolean animatePath, repeatDrawingPath;
    private DirectionPointListener resultCallback;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //https://www.mytrendin.com/draw-route-two-locations-google-maps-android/
    //https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-draw-path-two-points-using-google-directions-google-map-android-api-v2/

    public GetPathFromLocation(Context context, LatLng source, LatLng destination, ArrayList<LatLng> wayPoint, GoogleMap mMap, boolean animatePath, boolean repeatDrawingPath, DirectionPointListener resultCallback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.wayPoint = wayPoint;
        this.mMap = mMap;
        this.animatePath = animatePath;
        this.repeatDrawingPath = repeatDrawingPath;
        this.resultCallback = resultCallback;
    }

    synchronized public String getUrl(LatLng source, LatLng dest, ArrayList<LatLng> wayPoint) {

        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&mode=driving&origin="
                + source.latitude + "," + source.longitude + "&destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
        for (int centerPoint = 0; centerPoint < wayPoint.size(); centerPoint++) {
            if (centerPoint == 0) {
                url = url + "&waypoints=optimize:true|" + wayPoint.get(centerPoint).latitude + "," + wayPoint.get(centerPoint).longitude;
            } else {
                url = url + "|" + wayPoint.get(centerPoint).latitude + "," + wayPoint.get(centerPoint).longitude;
            }
        }
        url = url + "&key=" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key);

        return url;
    }

    public int getRandomColor() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... url) {

        String data;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL directionUrl = new URL(getUrl(source, destination, wayPoint));
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) directionUrl.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                }

                data = stringBuffer.toString();
                bufferedReader.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + e.toString());
                return null;
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Background Task data : " + data);

            //Second AsyncTask

            JSONObject jsonObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                // Starts parsing data
                DirectionHelper helper = new DirectionHelper();
                routes = helper.parse(jsonObject);
                Log.e(TAG, "Executing Routes : "/*, routes.toString()*/);

                return routes;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in Executing Routes : " + e.toString());
                return null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Background Task Exception : " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                if (j == 0) {    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String) point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                } else if (j == 1) { // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String) point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(8);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            //lineOptions.color(getRandomColor());

            if (animatePath) {
                final ArrayList<LatLng> finalPoints = points;
                ((AppCompatActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        PolylineOptions polylineOptions;
                        final Polyline greyPolyLine, blackPolyline;
                        final ValueAnimator polylineAnimator;

                        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                        for (LatLng latLng : finalPoints) {
                            builder.include(latLng);
                        }
                        polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                        polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                        polylineOptions.width(8);
                        polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                        polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                        polylineOptions.jointType(ROUND);
                        polylineOptions.addAll(finalPoints);
                        greyPolyLine = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                        polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                        polylineOptions.width(8);
                        polylineOptions.color(Color.WHITE);
                        polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                        polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                        polylineOptions.zIndex(5f);
                        polylineOptions.jointType(ROUND);

                        blackPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                        polylineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
                        polylineAnimator.setDuration(5000);
                        polylineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                        polylineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                                List<LatLng> points = greyPolyLine.getPoints();
                                int percentValue = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                                int size = points.size();
                                int newPoints = (int) (size * (percentValue / 100.0f));
                                List<LatLng> p = points.subList(0, newPoints);
                                blackPolyline.setPoints(p);
                            }
                        });

                        polylineAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                if (repeatDrawingPath) {
                                    List<LatLng> greyLatLng = greyPolyLine.getPoints();
                                    if (greyLatLng != null) {
                                        greyLatLng.clear();

                                    }
                                    polylineAnimator.start();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                                polylineAnimator.cancel();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                            }
                        });
                        polylineAnimator.start();
                    }
                });
            }

            Log.e(TAG, "PolylineOptions Decoded");
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if (resultCallback != null && lineOptions != null)
            resultCallback.onPath(lineOptions, distance, duration);
    }
}
```

**DirectionPointListener**

```
public interface DirectionPointListener {
    public void onPath(PolylineOptions polyLine,String distance,String duration);
}
```

Now draw path using below code in your Activity

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private ArrayList<LatLng> wayPoint = new ArrayList<>();
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

                /*Add Source Marker*/
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(source);
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                builder.include(source);

                /*Add Destination Marker*/
                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(destination);
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                builder.include(destination);

                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

                int width = mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth();
                int height = mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredHeight();
                int padding = (int) (width * 0.15); // offset from edges of the map 10% of screen

                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding);

                mMap.animateCamera(cu);

                new GetPathFromLocation(context, source, destination, wayPoint, mMap, true, false, new DirectionPointListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPath(PolylineOptions polyLine, String distance, String duration) {
                        mMap.addPolyline(polyLine);
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPath :: Distance :: " + distance + " Duration :: " + duration);

                        binding.txtDistance.setText(String.format(" %s", distance));
                        binding.txtDuration.setText(String.format(" %s", duration));
                    }
                }).execute();
            }
        });
    }
```

**OutPut**

[image]