# How to remove all the polylines from a map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Following

[How to draw a path between two markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)

I had to add lot of polylines between two markers, to make a path.

One of the markers is draggable, lets say source is draggable.

So, when user starts dragging the marker, the path previously drawn must be erased and a new path between new source and destination must be draw.

I am able to draw the new path, but how can i erase the previous path?

This is how the path is drawn:

```
    for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
        LatLng src = list.get(z);
        LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
        Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                        new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                .width(2).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true));
    }
```

One solution i can get is

> map.clear();

To clear all the polylines, markers etc.. and add the markers again, then drawn the path.

But as soon as I start dragging, the marker is cleared, hence not visible on the map :(

Thank You

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Keep track of the Polyline as you add it to the map:

```
Polyline polyline = this.mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().....);
```

Then when you want to remove it:

```
polyline.remove();
```

If you have lots of Polylines, just add them to a List as they are put on the map:

```
List<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();

for(....)
{
    polylines.add(this.mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()....));
}
```

And when you want to delete:

```
for(Polyline line : polylines)
{
    line.remove();
}

polylines.clear();
```

The key is to keep a reference to the Polyline objects and call .remove() on each one.

Comment: Thanks :) it helped

Answer (score 7):

I know this is very old question but I noticed that this is very common need. I found another way and I wanted to share it.

Here is the basic idea:

```
Polyline polylineFinal;
PolylineOptions polylineOptions;

loop {

    polylineOptions.add( new LatLng( latitude, longitude ) );

}

polylineOptions.width(2);
polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
polylineOptions.geodesic(true);

polylineFinal = map.addPolyline (polylineOptions);
```

Map's "addPolyline" method returns a single polyline which contains all the points. When I need to remove the points, I call polylineFinal's "remove" method.

```
polylineFinal.remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update

If you want to removes all markers, polylines, polygons, overlays, etc from the map use

```
mMap.clear(); //it will remove all additional objects from map
```

and if you only want to remove all or single polyline, polygon, marker etc see [@DiskDev Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14861563/revisions) above. In this case you must keep track of every single additional object you add to map