# Show multiple RoutePaths from same GeoPoint in Android

Tags: android

I wanted to show two Route Paths from same GeoPoint means from A-B and A-C.
Route1 contains GeoPoints from A-B and Route2 contains GeoPoints from A-C.  Please help me.

Comment: Have you displayed a single route between A-B? mean do you know how to display a route between geopoint?

Comment: Yes... I displayed...  I referred this article  http://djsolid.net/blog/android---draw-a-path-array-of-points-in-mapview

Comment: Then you know how to pass geopoint in that class. What you need to do is two times requesting google for providing route between 2 points. After displaying first one, just repeat that task.

Comment: I did but its displaying only second route.. My Code is

Comment: for (int j = 0; j <routes.size(); j++) {
path.clear();  
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
routeid= json.getString("routeid");

   if (routeid.equals(routes.get(j))) {

    int lat = json.getInt("latitude");
    int lng = json.getInt("longitude");
    g1 = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
    path.add(g1);
   }
 }
overlayList.add(new RoutePathOverlay(Monitor.this, path));
mapView.postInvalidate(); }               SORRY FOR THIS MESS

Comment: can't you do one things? When you request google for your route, don't display overlay. Second time request for second route and then merge both the route.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understood your idea...

Comment: Please tell me how to do that....

Answer (score 0):

Have you used following code

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
                + currentLat
                + ","
                + currentLng
                + "&destination="
                + lat
                + "," + lng + "&sensor=false";
```

Comment: no...And where do i pass this url...If i am not wrong this url will get new Map for me... It won't display route in my Existing MapView....

Comment: I want to display it in my Existing MapView...However i will try your code also Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [google-maps-android-api-v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/?hl=fr) and follow this:

[Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)