# Android google route using 3 points (Source point, destination point and via point)

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I am using google map to display route between two points . Now in my application i want to draw route in map using source point , destination point and via point.Please help me in this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2#answer-14702636)

But modify makeURL method to use

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints

```
makeURL(double sourceLat, double sourceLng, double viaLat, double viaLng, double DestLat, double DestLng);
drawPath(result);
```

Comment: Use that link but with a waypoint instead of two calls. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints