# google map getting current position and draw path

Tags: android, google-maps

how to get your current position in android and draw the path or line between your current position and the location that you That Is Touched.

Comment: Do you have problems retrieving user's location?

Answer (score 1):

To know your current location you require to get the latitude and longitude of your current loacation.

```
 public void getLatiLongi()
 {
     LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);   
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
               flati = location.getLatitude();
               flongi = location.getLongitude();
               System.out.println("Hello....................+lati+longi");
           }
     }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        LocationManager locationManager =
                (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!gpsEnabled) {
            gpsAlert();

        }
    }

    public void gpsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Enable GPS");  
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Yes")      
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        enableLocationSettings();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {        
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
                alertDialog.show();
    }
    private void enableLocationSettings() {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }
```

After that use a marker

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker.

You require latitude and longitude of your destination.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#polylines.

Use polylines to draw path from your location to the destination

[Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2). This link has a good explanation on the topic.

Comment: thx i'm going to try it