# Android path follow (Google map) Programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps

is it possible to follow a path on google map android (**Programmatically**) if my android device getting away from the path it notify or show alert that your not following your path

Help will be appriciated,
Thank's :)

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249920/how-to-draw-path-as-i-move-starting-from-my-current-location-using-google-maps)

Comment: Thanks dear but my question is different , if I have a path drawn on google map between two points and i wanna move from starting point to end point but android app force me to follow the exact path if a user not following the path it alert him that you are not on your path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by several ways. For example you can use [`PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(LatLng point, java.util.List<LatLng> polyline, boolean geodesic, double tolerance)`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-double-) from [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/?hl=en). In this case you need to check (with `isLocationOnPath()`) if user location laying on segment of the polyline of your path. Something like that:

```
if (!PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(userLocationPoint, pathPolyline.getPoints(), true, 50)) {
        // user away of pathPolyline more than 50 meters
        // show your alert here
        ...
    }
}
```

where `50` - is tolerance (in meters).
NB! It's not a complete solution - just approach.

Also you can use [geofence monitoring](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) for several waypoints (with a limit of 100 per device user).

Comment: Thank you it works for me and can you please elaborate what does actually do tolerance?

Comment: tolerance 50 means it will allow all the geo point which are in the range of 50 meter right ?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas You're welcome. From [documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-double-): "given point lies on or near a polyline, within a specified tolerance in meters. The polyline is composed of great circle segments if geodesic is true" - so it means 50 meters range for each "side" (100 m interval). Also, you can study source code of `PulyUtils.isLocationOnEdgeOrPath()`.