# draw my Rout on GoogleMaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to draw my Path on GoogleMap in android..as i move Forword a polyline should be drawn...i read some Tutorials about google maps and json parser but i that case we only draw path from start to destinition...I Also Read a tutorial that draws Overlay on MapView..but i want to draw it on GooglMap Class...the code for MapView OverLay is as follow but it didn't work with GooglMap

```
package com.example.PublicSafety;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.location.Location;

public class RouteOverlay extends Overlay{
    private List<Location> locations;
    private Paint pathPaint;
    private Paint postionPaint;
    public RouteOverlay() {
        pathPaint = new Paint();
        pathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        pathPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        pathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        pathPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

        postionPaint = new Paint();
        postionPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        postionPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Refer these links (And Try To Search Before Posting Questions Because The Are Already Having Answers)**

[Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)

[how to draw path between 2 points on google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154758/how-to-draw-path-between-2-points-on-google-map)

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-draw-route-between-two-geo.html