# multiple routes between two point in Google map

Tags: android

Hi friends iam making an android based app in which a user can see the multiple possible paths between two location points  means source-to-destination is it possible in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes You can draw multiple path between 2 locations using  Google Direction API

as :

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=SourcePoint&destination=DestinationPoint&sensor=false&units=metric&alternatives=true

Here **alternatives=true** is property which gives multiple paths . If You set this property as false one route will be provided

You can also refer  this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

and also these too : 1) [How to Draw Route in Google Maps API V2 from my location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262837/how-to-draw-route-in-google-maps-api-v2-from-my-location)

2) [Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)