# Convert FragmentManager to MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using this code to show Map

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

 }
```

And I'm also using markers, drag them and delete them. 
If I also want to make this map to be MapView to be able to draw lines using onDraw and TouchEvent in the same time, how can I convert it to MapView?

Comment: see this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2

Comment: I'm not want to draw paths and straight lines. I want to draw free lines using canvas.