# Draw the path between two LatLng on google map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

How I can get the path between these marker on google map fragment ?

```
    double latitude1=2.7;
    double longitude1=107.6;

    LatLng l1=new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);

    double latitude2=2.7;
    double longitude2=106.6;

    LatLng l2=new LatLng(latitude2, longitude2);


    MarkerOptions marker1 =new MarkerOptions().position(l1);
    MarkerOptions marker2 =new MarkerOptions().position(l2);
    map.addMarker(marker1);
    map.addMarker(marker2);
```

Comment: Are you want to get the route between two markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we will get source and destination points between which we have to draw route. Then we will pass these attribute to below function. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)