# How to draw path from current location to user entered location on map fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I'm curious if there is a way to draw the path from a devices current location to a user entered location.From researching the only methods I have come across are to get path from lat and long coordinates like this solution http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822 ,

My question is if there is a way to combine a users geo location and a user entered destination string to draw the path.I'm guessing this would involve reverse geo coding or am I wrong?

The current interface looks like this and I'm using Google maps API v2:

[image]

Comment: refer this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for how to do a polyline in android map api v2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

Tip save your line as a kml file for interoperability so other apps will be able to import the file and show the same line on a map.