# Route from source to destination in google maps by selecting a location from ListView

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a ListView of locations.when user clicks on the particular location from list view then the route must be shown from current location to the user selected location.

How do i do that?

Comment: okay i will try this first and check

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to fetch the location name on click in listview.
2. Then you need to get lat and long for the location name selected and also fetch lat and long for your current location.
3. Then use this code

Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri .parse("maps.google.com/maps?saddr="; + current_latitude + "," + current_longitude + "&daddr=" + Dest_lat + "," + Dest_long));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"); startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i tried your solution but i am not getting the route..if there are any examples on this , then please send me the links.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice answer in stackoverflow and it works like a charm for me.
Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)

Even you can add your own logic to store all locations in custom ListView and then get the directions from your current location to any other location on map.