# Draw path between two points on the map-google maps using Eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm writing program in android google map v2 .

I created markers as ArrayList

Now,  I want to find the street, between two points on the map how ???

Help me !!

Thanks

Comment: you question is possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2

Comment: Do you want to get turn by turn navigation between the 2 points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Following Code:-

```
/************************** Drawing polyline if there are more than 1 latlngs **************/
            if (arraylist_lat_lon.size() > 1) {

                PolylineOptions polyline_options = new PolylineOptions()
                        .addAll(arraylist_lat_lon).color(Color.GREEN).width(2);

                polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polyline_options);

            }
```

Note: **arraylist_lat_lon** : Array List where you are storing your LatLngs

Comment: Could you detailed instructions?