# Google Maps Marker Animation

Tags: android, routes

I'm trying to move a marker on google maps with a driving route. I managed to animate the marker on the map but I couldn't move it according to a specific route. any help is appreciated thanks in advance.
This is the code I used to animate the marker:

```
final long duration = 11200;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
Projection proj = googleMap.getProjection();
Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
  public void run() {

    long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
    float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
    double lng = t * target.longitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.longitude;
    double lat = t * target.latitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.latitude;
    LatLng posetion2=new LatLng(lat,lng);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
            new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(posetion2)
            .bearing(9) 
            .tilt(10)
            .zoom(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
            .build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition)


    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find your answer in this question 
[Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)
you will use the API to get the Points between the two Location then use them to animate your marker