# Path between two very far points on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, path, routes, google-maps-markers

I am trying to develop very basic GPS App and want to highlight path between two cities. I used the code in the following post

[Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)

by zeeshan0026.

And the code works fine but when you highlight path between two very far cities then it shows the straight kind of path. I think the problem with the number of LatLng points return by the decodepoly function i am trying to change the shift but nothing helps.

Please somebody help me in this regard.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directions API URLs are restricted to approximately 2000 characters, after URL Encoding. As some Directions API URLs may involve many locations along a path, be aware of this limit when constructing your URLs.

For more accurate path between very far cities, we need to use the polyutil.encode and decode functions.