# Google Maps route

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I have researched a lot on google maps android to dynamically plot the route as the person travels. I found that polyline gives a closed polygon with multiple points on it, which does not look good. So what is the best method to plot the exact route as traveled by a person as per the latitude and longitude.

Comment: Hi you should draw polyline line as person move

Comment: Hello Saveen, polyline would draw a polygon right. So if I travel from A->B-> C. It would give me a triangle with vertices A, B, C. What I am looking for is the path A->B->C. Not a closed loop.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the Google Maps Directions API to build your route map.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro. Also refer to the detailed SO answer which may help you understand its implementation.
[Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2).