# create itinary google maps android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, directions

After using gps for geolocalization, i want to create an line to show the itinary between two points. I know i need to use the polyline but after the JSON parsing, I don't know how to use the polyline options and I don't know how to use the part of Json named "steps". For the Http conection, i use the Volley Library. This my code:

```
public void geoLocate(View view){

        String start = start_address.getText().toString();
        String destination = destination_address.getText().toString();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getActivity());
        try {

            List<android.location.Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(start,1);
            final Address adress1 =  list.get(0);
            String  start_adress = adress1.getLocality();
            double lat_start = adress1.getLatitude();
            double lng_start = adress1.getLongitude();


            list = gc.getFromLocationName(destination,1);
            Address adress2 =  list.get(0);
            String  destination_adress = adress2.getLocality();
            double lat_destination = adress2.getLatitude();
            double lng_destination = adress2.getLongitude();

            if (start_marker != null || destination_marker != null){
                start_marker.remove();
                destination_marker.remove();
            }

            options_start = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(start_adress)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                    .position(new LatLng(lat_start, lng_start));
            start_marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options_start);
            options_destination = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(destination_adress)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                    .position(new LatLng(lat_destination, lng_destination));
            destination_marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options_destination);
            reservation.setClickable(true);
            reservation.setEnabled(true);
            reservation.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            reservation.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            if(reservation.isClickable()) {
                reservation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
            }

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            builder.include(start_marker.getPosition());
            builder.include(destination_marker.getPosition());
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
            final StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&language=fr");
            url.append("&origin=");
            url.append(start.replace(" ", "+"));
            url.append("&destination=");
            url.append(destination.replace(" ", "+"));


            final Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        String status = jsonResponse.getString("status");

                        if (status.equals("OK")){
                            JSONArray parentArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("routes");
                                JSONObject routes  = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                if(routes != null){

                                    JSONArray legsArray = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
                                    JSONObject legsObject = legsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    if (legsObject != null){

                                        JSONObject distance = legsObject.getJSONObject("distance");
                                        if (distance != null){
                                            String distanceText = distance.getString("text");
                                            distance_matrix.append(" "+distanceText);
                                        }

                                        JSONArray stepsArray = legsObject.getJSONArray("steps");
                                        JSONObject stepsObject = stepsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                        if (stepsObject != null){


                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            };


            ItineraireRequest itineraireRequest = new ItineraireRequest(url.toString(), responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            queue.add(itineraireRequest);
            int padding = 125; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cu);



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Can you give a solution adapted to my code to make that, please?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14702636/5165244) should be of some assistance

Comment: HttpClient is decrepated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could help, the "getDocument()" do all the work

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
        Document doc = md.getDocument(formatAddress(ORIGIN_TEXT, formatAddress(DESTINATION_TEXT, MODE, getApplicationContext());
        if (doc != null) {

            int duration = md.getDurationValue(doc);

            if (duration > 0) {
                try {

                    ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
                    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(9).color(R.color.splash_blue).geodesic(true);

                    for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                        rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                    }

                    AccessLocationActivity.this.mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
```

### UPDATED

try this

```
public void geoLocate(View view){

        String start = start_address.getText().toString();
        String destination = destination_address.getText().toString();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getActivity());
        try {

            List<android.location.Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(start,1);
            final Address adress1 =  list.get(0);
            String  start_adress = adress1.getLocality();
            double lat_start = adress1.getLatitude();
            double lng_start = adress1.getLongitude();


            list = gc.getFromLocationName(destination,1);
            Address adress2 =  list.get(0);
            String  destination_adress = adress2.getLocality();
            double lat_destination = adress2.getLatitude();
            double lng_destination = adress2.getLongitude();

            if (start_marker != null || destination_marker != null){
                start_marker.remove();
                destination_marker.remove();
            }

            options_start = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(start_adress)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                    .position(new LatLng(lat_start, lng_start));
            start_marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options_start);
            options_destination = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(destination_adress)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                    .position(new LatLng(lat_destination, lng_destination));
            destination_marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options_destination);
            reservation.setClickable(true);
            reservation.setEnabled(true);
            reservation.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            reservation.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            if(reservation.isClickable()) {
                reservation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
            }

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            builder.include(start_marker.getPosition());
            builder.include(destination_marker.getPosition());
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
            final StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&language=fr");
            url.append("&origin=");
            url.append(start.replace(" ", "+"));
            url.append("&destination=");
            url.append(destination.replace(" ", "+"));


            GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
            Document doc = md.getDocument(formatAddress(start), formatAddress(destination), GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING, getApplicationContext());
            if (doc != null) {

                int duration = md.getDurationValue(doc);

                if (duration > 0) {
                    try {

                        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
                        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(9).color(R.color.colorPrimary).geodesic(true);

                        for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                        }

                        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you can give me this but with my script, please?

Comment: In fact what is GMapV2Direction.class? I don't have any class named GMapV2Direction

Comment: sorry for my late anwser you could import that class here https://github.com/KAPLANDROID/Shortest-Path-Direction-on-Google-Maps-v2-for-Android/blob/master/KaplanDroidShortestPathDirection/src/com/kaplandroid/shortestpathdirection/googlemaps/GMapV2Direction.java

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary) is a great wrapper on top of the Google DirectionsAPI if you are willing to give it a shot.

More detailed explanation [here](http://www.akexorcist.com/2015/12/google-direction-library-for-android-en.html).