# How can i show markers close to a route path in android maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an application with a map Activity. I also have put some markers on it.

I have found in this SO question how to draw a path between 2 points:
[Answer : Draw path between two points using Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2)

How can i show only those of my markers that are close to this path in a radius for example 500m ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath` method from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/):

> Computes whether the given point lies on or near a polyline, within a specified tolerance in meters. The polyline is composed of great circle segments if geodesic is true, and of Rhumb segments otherwise. The polyline is not closed -- the closing segment between the first point and the last point is not included.
>
> `public static boolean isLocationOnPath(LatLng point, List<LatLng> polyline, boolean geodesic, double tolerance)`

You will need to iterate over your markers and make them visible or invisible depending on the returned value of `PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath` with your desired tolerance (500 in your example):

```
for(Marker marker : markers) {
    if (PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(marker.getPosition(), yourRoutePath, false, 500)) {
        marker.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        marker.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```